# sshagent block in Jenkinsfile causes NotSerializableException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkinsfile in a pipeline job, I need to scp a javadoc jar to a remote host.  I've been struggling all day with required pieces to get this done, and it's still not working.

I'm attempting to use "sshagent" for this.  I defined a "username with private key" credential, which I'm referencing from the block.  Inside the block, I construct a handful of scp/ssh shell commands to run.

My code block within the stage currently looks like this:

```
  println "JP_MechIdPrivateKey[${JP_MechIdPrivateKey}] class[${JP_MechIdPrivateKey.class.name}]"
  sshagent (credentials: [JP_MechIdPrivateKey]) {
    sh "scp ${javadocJarPath} ${JP_JavadocJarHost}:/tmp"
    sh "ssh ${JP_JavadocJarHost} \"cd ${JP_JavadocRootRemotePath}; rm -rf ${versionNumber}; mkdir ${versionNumber}\""
    sh "ssh ${JP_JavadocJarHost} \"cd ${JP_JavadocRootRemotePath}; jar xvf /tmp/${baseFileName}\""
  }
```

When I run this, I see the following:

```
JP_MechIdPrivateKey[<myusername>-private-key] class[java.lang.String]

[ssh-agent] Using credentials <myusername>
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Java/JNR ssh-agent
[ssh-agent] Skipped registering BouncyCastle, not running on a remote agent
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] sh
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[usl-parent] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] sh
...
java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
...
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field locals
```

The stacktrace doesn't provide any direct clue of what line from the script is at issue.  I tried commenting out the "sshagent" block, and the exception does not occur (and the job doesn't do anything useful), so it's clear the error is coming from that block.

I've heard that serialization issues usually indicate going to a @NonCPS method, but I don't understand how to transform this to resolve this.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is that you key storage class is not Serializable.

Comment: And how does that information help me?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read you question carefully and was too hasty with my comment. I am using sshagent+scp successfully, in my case the key is stored directly in Jenkins. Do you use "path to keyfile"?